# Unknown column ' ' in 'NEW' when creating trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, database-trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER tr_client_log
AFTER INSERT
ON client FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO clientlog(clientID, message)
        VALUES(new.id,CONCAT('Hi ', NEW.name, ', welcome to our petshop.'));
END$$
```

DELIMITER ;

> #1054 - Unknown column 'id' in 'NEW'

```
CREATE TABLE `client` (
 `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `surname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `c_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `pnumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

CREATE TABLE `clientlog` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `clientID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `message` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`clientID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: (1) What is your question?  (2) What database are you using?  (3) What are you trying to do?  (4) What does your database look like?

Comment: sorry i updated the tables. Im using mySQL on phpmyadmin. Im new to this. IM geting an error when i want to create a trigger

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear enough: there is no `id` column in table `client`. Presumably, you want `c_id` instead:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER tr_client_log
AFTER INSERT
ON client FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO clientlog(clientID, message)
        VALUES(NEW.c_id, CONCAT('Hi ', NEW.name, ', welcome to our petshop.'));
END$$
```